# parse xml column in sql server to python pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, xml-parsing

I want to parse an xml column in a MS SQL Server table into a pandas dataframe.

I can get some of the way there.

I can create a connection object to SQL Server

```
import pyodbc
from lxml import etree

conn_str = (
r'Driver={SQL Server};'
r'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
r'Database=myDB;'
r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I now want to iterate over a row object (from a cursor?) and use lxml to parse each line one at a time and append to a dataframe in pandas.
I can't get parse to iterate over rows? Maybe this is the wrong approach?

```
  tree = etree.parse(row)
```

doesn't work.

Then I think I need to build a dictionary of parsed elements similar to below

```
root = tree.getroot()


# Parse out data from XML
data = []
for child in root:
    datarow = {}
    for leaf in child:
        datarow[leaf.tag] = leaf.text
    data.append(datarow)
```

And then finally convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe.
Crucially I don't want to have to know the xml structure in advance. 
These are my thoughts, but if there is a better way please tell me.
Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would read_sql work for you? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

try:

```
df = pd.read_sql(yoursqlstring, cnxn)
```

Comment: Thanks - that works to give me a one column dataframe with the xml columns from SQL Server now a pandas column. But how do I parse with lxml ?

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of what your  current one column dataframe looks like and what output you hope to receive?